# Android issue with implementing customised themes

Tags: android, themes

My android project

`AndoidManifest.xml` has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
         <meta-data 
             android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
             android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" /> 
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

When I am trying to implement a customised theme under `res\values\themes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
      <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
      <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"  
          parent="@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
       <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> 
       </style>      <!-- ActionBar styles -->

       <style name="MyActionBar"            
           parent="@style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
       <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
       </style>  
</resources>
```

I am getting erros specifying

`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar'.` and 
`Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/
 Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to write `android:` before style, namely `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`.

Comment: Now comes up with error `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'android:background' with value '@drawable/ actionbar_background').`

Comment: Do you have a drawable called "actionbar_background" in your project?

Comment: sorry I am new to this , where do i CHeck ?

Comment: Check your res/drawable or res/drawable-something directories. Is there a actionbar_background.png or actionbar_background.xml?

Comment: Nope I don't . I am referring to this example `http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.htm` they don't seem to have one either. Can you please advise. What should I do to fix the issue?

Comment: Maybe you can temporarily use a simple color for now. Like <item name="android:background">#ffccff</item>. You can add your own image background later.

Answer (score 2):

They have not included examples of all the files used or how they made the files or that files needs to be created.

It seems that beside that they have forgotten the use of @android they didn't mention that files like actionbar_background.xml have to be created under res/drawable/ in this case or that themes.xml should be created under res/values/

They seem to have created the styles(for the pictures in the guide) using:
http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

And files generated themselves following:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

They do the same things in the rest of the chapter. The guide is quite confusing when you are new.

From the question asked I assume that they have used the [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) at android developers.

Answer (score 0):

you can add themes.xml into styles.xml